# .net core web api with .net standard library EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am having the weirdest of issues in a .net core web api project I have added a .net standard library which houses my models and EF code first. This all works when I deploy to IIS Express but when I attempt to publish it to IIS, the build fails.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\logs\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" Version="4.5.4" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0-*</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\mobileapp\forms\xxxCallManager\xxxDalCoreStandard\xxxDalCoreStandardxxxlDalCoreStandard.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>


</Project>
```

As you see from about their is no mention of system.refelection so i can only asume its one the nuget in my standard project that is messing it up below is my standard.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="2.0.1" />

  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
   <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The error I am getting is as follows now I tried adding the nuget of system.reflection but still no joy

[image]

**Edit 1**
The suggestion below helped a bit but now I am stuck with this error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The command ""dotnet" exec --runtimeconfig
>   "C:\Work\xxxApp\xxxlApis\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\FuelApis.runtimeconfig.json"
>   --depsfile "C:\Work\FxxxApp\xxxlApis\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.0\xxxApis.deps.json"
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation\2.0.3\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.dll"
>   @"obj\Release\netcoreapp2.0\microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.viewcompilation.rsp""
>   exited with code 1.   xxxlApis        0

Comment: Can you try publishing using dotnet cli. `dotnet publish -c Release -r win7_x64 --self-contained `

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong version of EF tools in the first project, it looks like a 1.0 preview version, it should be:

```
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.*" />
```

also I would remove this part:

```
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="System.Text.Encoding.CodePages">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

I don't think you need that especially the hint path part. I would try remove that altogether

Comment: that kinda of help but i am facing a new .net core error wish this was alll more stable than this tbh

Comment: I must add this works fine in iis express which is the weird part see edit 2 above